# jqGrid frozen columns when there are hidden rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have got a grid with some hidden rows. I need to freeze the first two columns but I've seen that if there are some hidden rows the 'setFrozenColumns' doesn't work.
Anybody who had the same problem? Can you help me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean hidden rows or hidden columns? Currently - as of 4.3.2 - frozen columns have [the following limitations](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3afrozencolumns):

> The following limitations tell you when frozen columns can not be set-up
>
> - When TreeGrid is enabled
> - When SubGrid is enabled
> - When cellEdit is enabled
> - When inline edit is used - the frozen columns can not be edit.
> - When sortable columns are enabled - grid parameter sortable is set to true or is function
> - When scroll is set to true or 1
> - When Data grouping is enabled

So if you are using a TreeGrid or SubGrid, frozen columns will not work at all.

If you mean that you have hidden *columns* then frozen columns should work - you may need to post code or a small example demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I mean hidden ROWS. 
Here an example (it didn't make by me):
[demo][1]


  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/YWVA8/144/

If you try to hide a row in that way: 

    document.getElementById("1").style.display = 'none';

and then freeze the columns, the framework doesn't work properly:

     $("#list47").jqGrid("destroyFrozenColumns") 
                    .jqGrid("setColProp","id",{frozen:true})
                    .jqGrid("setColProp","invdate",{frozen:true})                 
                    .jqGrid("setFrozenColumns")
                     .trigger("reloadGrid");

Answer (score 0):

This is a complete example:

```
var mydata = [
{
id: "1",
invdate: "2010-05-24",
name: "test",
note: "note",
tax: "10.00",
total: "2111.00"},
{
id: "2",
invdate: "2010-05-25",
name: "test2",
note: "note2",
tax: "20.00",
total: "320.00"},
{
id: "3",
invdate: "2007-09-01",
name: "test3",
note: "note3",
tax: "30.00",
total: "430.00"},
{
id: "4",
invdate: "2007-10-04",
name: "test",
note: "note",
tax: "10.00",
total: "210.00"},
{
id: "5",
invdate: "2007-10-05",
name: "test2",
note: "note2",
tax: "20.00",
total: "320.00"},
{
id: "6",
invdate: "2007-09-06",
name: "test3",
note: "note3",
tax: "30.00",
total: "430.00"},
{
id: "7",
invdate: "2007-10-04",
name: "test",
note: "note",
tax: "10.00",
total: "210.00"},
{
id: "8",
invdate: "2007-10-03",
name: "test2",
note: "note2",
amount: "300.00",
tax: "21.00",
total: "320.00"},
{
id: "9",
invdate: "2007-09-01",
name: "test3",
note: "note3",
amount: "400.00",
tax: "30.00",
total: "430.00"},
{
id: "11",
invdate: "2007-10-01",
name: "test",
note: "note",
amount: "200.00",
tax: "10.00",
total: "210.00"},
{
id: "12",
invdate: "2007-10-02",
name: "test2",
note: "note2",
amount: "300.00",
tax: "20.00",
total: "320.00"},
{
id: "13",
invdate: "2007-09-01",
name: "test3",
note: "note3",
amount: "400.00",
tax: "30.00",
total: "430.00"},
{
id: "14",
invdate: "2007-10-04",
name: "test",
note: "note",
amount: "200.00",
tax: "10.00",
total: "210.00"},
{
id: "15",
invdate: "2007-10-05",
name: "test2",
note: "note2",
amount: "300.00",
tax: "20.00",
total: "320.00"},
{
id: "16",
invdate: "2007-09-06",
name: "test3",
note: "note3",
amount: "400.00",
tax: "30.00",
total: "430.00"},
{
id: "17",
invdate: "2007-10-04",
name: "test",
note: "note",
amount: "200.00",
tax: "10.00",
total: "210.00"},
{
id: "18",
invdate: "2007-10-03",
name: "test2",
note: "note2",
amount: "300.00",
tax: "20.00",
total: "320.00"},
{
id: "19",
invdate: "2007-09-01",
name: "test3",
note: "note3",
amount: "400.00",
tax: "30.00",
total: "430.00"},
{
id: "21",
invdate: "2007-10-01",
name: "test",
note: "note",
amount: "200.00",
tax: "10.00",
total: "210.00"},
{
id: "22",
invdate: "2007-10-02",
name: "test2",
note: "note2",
amount: "300.00",
tax: "20.00",
total: "320.00"},
{
id: "23",
invdate: "2007-09-01",
name: "test3",
note: "note3",
amount: "400.00",
tax: "30.00",
total: "430.00"},
{
id: "24",
invdate: "2007-10-04",
name: "test",
note: "note",
amount: "200.00",
tax: "10.00",
total: "210.00"},
{
id: "25",
invdate: "2007-10-05",
name: "test2",
note: "note2",
amount: "300.00",
tax: "20.00",
total: "320.00"},
{
id: "26",
invdate: "2007-09-06",
name: "test3",
note: "note3",
amount: "400.00",
tax: "30.00",
total: "430.00"},
{
id: "27",
invdate: "2007-10-04",
name: "test",
note: "note",
amount: "200.00",
tax: "10.00",
total: "210.00"},
{
id: "28",
invdate: "2007-10-03",
name: "test2",
note: "note2",
amount: "300.00",
tax: "20.00",
total: "320.00"},
{
id: "29",
invdate: "2007-09-01",
name: "test3",
note: "note3",
amount: "400.00",
tax: "30.00",
total: "430.00"}
];
jQuery("#list47").jqGrid({
data: mydata,
datatype: "local",
height: 150,
rowNum: 999999,
scroll: false,
shrinkToFit: false,
width: 350,
colNames: ['Inv No', 'Date', 'Client', 'Amount', 'Tax', 'Total', 'Notes'],
colModel: [
    {
    name: 'id',
    index: 'id',
    width: 60,
    sortable: false, frozen: true},
{
    name: 'invdate',
    index: 'invdate',
    width: 90,
    sorttype: "date",
    formatter: "date"},
{
    name: 'name',
    index: 'name',
    width: 100},
{
    name: 'amount',
    index: 'amount',
    width: 80,
    align: "right",
    sorttype: "float",
    formatter: "number"},
{
    name: 'tax',
    index: 'tax',
    width: 80,
    align: "right",
    sorttype: "float"},
{
    name: 'total',
    index: 'total',
    width: 80,
    align: "right",
    sorttype: "float"},
{
    name: 'note',
    index: 'note',
    width: 150,
    sortable: false}
],

pager: "#plist47",
viewrecords: true,
multiselect: true,
caption: "single selection",
beforeSelectRow: function(rowid, e)
{
    //jQuery("#list47").jqGrid('resetSelection');
    //return(true);
}

});



document.getElementById("1").style.display = 'none';
$("#list47").jqGrid("destroyFrozenColumns") 
                .jqGrid("setColProp","id",{frozen:true})
                .jqGrid("setColProp","invdate",{frozen:true})                 
                .jqGrid("setFrozenColumns")
```

In this case just the header is frozen and not the whole column.